# How to convert a byte[index] to a simple character or some other better representation?

Tags: java

I want to convert a byte[i] to a character so that I can store it along with my password so that when I hash the password I can added the character stream (Salt) with the new password. The output below is the bytes but I want to have the character representation or something that would work.

I do not really want to explicitly cast the byte to a character

```
 char c = (char) byte[i];
```

Like the above. Is there a better way of changing the byte[i] to a character.

Code:

```
package Encrypto;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class TestWhirl {
    static SecureRandom rn = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] a) {
         byte bytes[] = new byte[20];
          rn.nextBytes(bytes);
          for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
             char[] temp = Character.toChars(bytes[i]);
              char c = (char) bytes[i];
              System.out.println(Integer.toString(i)     + "  " +  
                                 Byte.toString(bytes[i]) + "  " + 
                                 c); 
          }
    }
}
```

### Output:

0    3
1    118
2    65
3    50
4    51
5    19
6   -104
7   -43
8    121
9   -76
10  -88
11  -69
12  -80
13   93
14  -75
15  -110
16   84
17   30
18   36
19  -123

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) or hexadecimal notation. Both are "readable" notations. Base64 is shorter than hexadecimal, but hexadecimal is still easier for humans to read.

For example, "example string" becomes "RXhhbXBsZSBzdHJpbmc=" in base64 and "6578616d706c6520737472696e67" hexadecimal.